# python __metaclass__ doesn’t work

Tags: python, metaclass

```
   class UpperAttrMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(upperattr_metaclass, future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attr):
        attrs = ((name, value) for name, value in future_class_attr.items() if not name.startswith('__'))
        uppercase_attr = dict((name.upper(), value) for name, value in attrs)
        return type.__new__(upperattr_metaclass,future_class_name, future_class_parents, uppercase_attr)



class boo(object):
    __metaclass__ = UpperAttrMetaClass
    bar = 'birr'


print(hasattr(boo,'BAR'))
```

my goal is to transform the attribute named 'bar' of the class boo into uppercase 'BAR' using **metaclass**,but the program's result is 'False' showing that it doesn't work ,i am confused.

Comment: Are you using python 2 syntax for python 3? Just a guess, i don't remember the exact semantics...

Comment: You're on Python3 and what you want is: `class boo(object, metaclass=UpperAttrMetaClass): ...`. What you've shown only works in Python2.

Comment: @Chris_Rands thanks.you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The code is incorrect in a way that it filters out, and does not add back, all metthods or attributes starting with `__`. But that would not prevent it from properly uppercase your other attributes.

So, what is likely taking place is that you are using this with Python 3, and using the Python 2 syntax for metaclasses, which is adding a  `__metaclass__` attribute in the class body.

If you simply change the class creatin to Python 3 it should work:

```
class boo(metaclass=UpperAttrMetaclass):
    ...
```

Other than that, you are filtering out any magic names that could be defined in the class body - so `__init__`, all the other special methods, and even `__slots__` would be left out the actuall class. If that is not your intent, you have to change that - you can do the filtering and uppercasing in a single line:

```
def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace):
    namespace = {(name.upper() if not name.startswith('__') else name)  : value for namespace.__items__()}
    return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
```

I used your algorithm, but note that actual non-magic atttributes starting, but not ending, with `__` will be processed and uppercased: the name mangling that adds the class name to such attributes takes place at compile time, before any metclass method is called (even before setting the item in the namespace returned by the metaclass' `__prepare__`)). So, if you want to skip an attribute such as  `__name`, the check should be for `if '__' not in name`.

(also, please note this is explicit Python 3) .

Furthermore, in order to be able to be sure about the above statement of name mangling taking place before anything else, I made a small test in the terminal. As it is a nice example to demonstrate this, I am pasting this test bellow in order to document it for other users looking for related issues:

```
class M(type):
    def __prepare__(self, name):
        class N(dict):
            def __setitem__(self, item, value):
                print(item)
                super().__setitem__(item, value)
        return N()
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, ns):
        print(ns)
        return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, ns)


class A(metaclass=M):
    __hidden = 0
```

Output for this, when creating `A`:

```
__module__
__qualname__
_A__hidden
{'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'A', '_A__hidden': 0}
```

(Note that in your code, `__module__` and `__qualname__` would not be passed to the actual class creation)